# Pass the dynamically created query (according to condition) in @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I am using the @Query annotation to execute the query in spring repository.
But I want to change the some part or make a new query according to the condition and pass in the @Query("pass here the query according to condition")

This is my query

```
  @Query("SELECT ds.symptom  FROM DoctorSymptomsModel ds where ds.doctorId = :doctorId and ds.isMostUsed = :isMostUsed)
```

If some condition satisfy then concat the "ORDER BY createdDate" part in query.

Or

Can I make the variable and set the query in that variable and set like that

```
  String query = SELECT ds.symptom  FROM DoctorSymptomsModel ds where
  ds.doctorId = :doctorId and ds.isMostUsed = :isMostUsed

  if(result){

  query = SELECT ds.symptom  FROM DoctorSymptomsModel ds where ds.doctorId =
  :doctorId and ds.isMostUsed = :isMostUsed ORDER BY createdDate


}

    //pass the query variable here
    @Query(query)
    List<String> findDoctorSymptomsModelList(@Param("doctorId") long doctorId,
    @Param("isMostUsed") boolean isMostUsed);
```

Comment: I am also searching if your idea is possible.

Comment: I have a idea to to this , but I will answer them in some time , sorry

Answer (score 2):

To make a dynamic query, you should think about CriteriaQuery. Take a look at this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) for brief introduction.